# prevent/block direct access to a thank you page

Tags: redirect

how to prevent/block direct access to a thank you page, only access if redirected from submiiting a form (in a different page)?

Comment: Is the page with the form the same or is the form implemented on many/all pages?

Comment: the form is implemented in one page only ,  it's cf7 form so the redirection works well, what I still need is to block direct access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the form is redirecting from one page only, you can easily use [`wp_get_referer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_referer/) to check for it and if not, redirect.

```
add_action('template_redirect', function() {
    // ID of the thank you page
    if (!is_page(12345)) {
        return;
    }

    // coming from the form, so all is fine
    if (wp_get_referer() === 'URL_OF_FORM') {
        return;
    }

    // we are on thank you page
    // visitor is not coming from form
    // so redirect to home
    wp_redirect(get_home_url());
    exit;
} );
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `die`/`exit` after redirect?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż good catch, added it

Comment: @kero, I have one doubt what URL I have to use it in URL_OF_FORM? I added your code and  I have a form on the contact us page

Comment: @user9437856 try with the URL of the contact page (complete one you can just copy and paste from your browser). If that does not work, you can do `error_log(wp_get_referer());` with `WP_DEBUG_LOG` enabled and should see the correct URL in your debug.log

Comment: @kero, Yes, If I try my whole URL http://example.com/contact-us/ then it's working. If I add /contact-us/ or contact-us/ then it's not working.

Comment: @user9437856 Yes, that is to be expected. You can use PHP's [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/parse_url) and check against path to achieve this

Comment: Let me check this. Give me sometime

Comment: I tried like this  if (wp_get_referer() === get_site_url().'/contact-us/')  and it's working

Comment: upvote from my side

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why the above code don't work for me. However the below code worked perfectly.

```
<?php
    function thank_you_rd(){
        if ( ! is_page('thank-you')) {
            return;
        }
        if (wp_get_referer() == '/contact-us/') {
            return;
        }
        wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
    }
    add_action('template_redirect', 'thank_you_rd');
?>
```